# Calculate speed between two location points in Android

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

This seems like it should be simple enough, but I can't seem to get a clear example of how to calculate my speed using Android's Location Services.

All I want to do is calculate my speed based on my previous and current GPS position.  getSpeed() doesn't work, because it needs to be set at some point using setSpeed().

So is there any sample code out there that I can run in Eclipse against my Android emulator running a GPX file, that will show me my pace in any measure (meters, feet, miles, etc., doesn't matter - I can always convert this to what I need).

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> getSpeed() doesn't work, because it needs to be set at some point using setSpeed().

(In case you are using an actual device -- ). No, the speed is determined by the GPS chipset and it should be more accurate than getting the  distance and time between two consecutive locations. You do not need to `setSpeed()` . Call [`hasSpeed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#hasSpeed%28%29) to see if the speed is valid.

---

(In case you're not using an actual device)
 I've had good success using the mock location provider where you can set the `Location` object you want with `setSpeed()`  in meters/second

Here are some ways of doing this :

- [Mocking using NMEA](http://knol.google.com/k/android-s-mock-locationprovider#)
- [Mocking using code](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=40151FCD26222877E151C3EEFB406EED?recipeId=1229&recipeFrom=ViewTOC)

Answer (score 2):

Do you just mean something like this?  Gives you the speed in m/s.

oldLocation.distanceTo(newLocation) / (newLocation.getTime() - oldLocation.getTime())

Comment: this probably will work but may sometimes give a bit of crappy results (i.e. high oscillations due to one miscalculated location). You can make it smoother by calculating the average of more location data sets.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `getTime()` returns milliseconds, not seconds. So you're off by a factor 10^3 if you expect `m/s`.